# c++ creating objects or structs based on conditions

Tags: c++, object, user-interface, conditional-statements

I'm coming from a couple years of java classes to learning c++, and I was wondering how I would create objects based on user set conditions.  I was planning on making a Lotus game board (Chinese Parcheesi).  Is there any way I can create class objects for the game's position or pieces based on the number of players that the user inputs at setup?  I heard that I can't create objects in conditionals, maybe I can call different setup methods in a different class?  Thanks for the input, on a side note, does anyone know a good c++ GUI for a game board?

Comment: What to you mean by "I can't create objects in conditionals"?

Comment: Whoever told you you can't create objects in conditionals is wrong.

Comment: if(players == 3){ player1= new player player 2 = new player player 3 = new player}

Comment: I can't declare and instantiate objects in an if statement

Comment: I think you need to see some examples of the new keyword.

Comment: Can you create objects without conditionals?

Comment: What they probably told you was making objects _with automatic scope_ is sort of pointless inside a conditional in the way you're thinking.  There's _easy_ ways to rewrite the code to make sense though.

Answer (score 0):

As previous commenters have noted, you can indeed declare variables in a conditional:

```
#include <iostream>    
int main() { 
  if( 3 > 2) { 
    int i = 3;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  } 
return 0;
}
```

But that's probably not really what you want to do.  The standard way of doing things like this in C++ is to use vectors, something like:

```
class PlayerType {
private:    
  std::string name;  
  double score;
}; // obviously needs more functionality to be useful
int numPlayers = 3; 
vector< class PlayerType > players( numPlayers );
```

So you shouldn't need to do any conditional declarations.